# MongoDB: Why is Array.find on comments (an array) property returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Probably a silly issue, but why is the Array.find method not working as expected when working in this case? I'm trying to query a specific comment, which involves fetching the post document that has a comments property from the DB. It is from this comments array that I'd like to extract said comment object. For whatever reason, the code below doesn't work. Why?

Below are the code snippets

```
// Post document from which the comments are extracted
const post = await Post.findById(postId).populate({
  path: "comments",
  select: "addedBy id"
});

// Resulting post.comments array
[
  { "id": "5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556", "addedBy": "5b8528131719dc141cf95c99" },
  { "id": "5d9b0ba2f28afc5c3013d4df", "addedBy": "5b8528131719dc141cf95c99" },
  { "id": "5d9b0c26f28afc5c3013d4e0", "addedBy": "5b8528131719dc141cf95c99" }
];

// For instance if commentId is '5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556' 
// the resulting comment object should be {"id":"5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556","addedBy":"5b8528131719dc141cf95c99"}
// However, commentToDelete is undefined
const commentId = "5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556";

const commentToDelete = comments.find(comment => comment["id"] === commentId);
```

**Edit: Here's the full deleteComment controller code**

```
async function deleteComment(req, res, userId, postId, commentId) {
  const post = await Post.findById(postId).populate({
    path: 'comments',
    select: 'addedBy id',
  });

  const commentToDelete = post.comments.find(
    comment => comment['id'] === commentId
  );

  if (commentToDelete.addedBy !== userId) {
    return res
      .status(403)
      .json({ message: 'You are not allowed to delete this comment' });
  }

  await Comment.findByIdAndDelete(commentId);

  const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
    post.id,
    { $pull: { comments: { id: commentId } } },
    { new: true, safe: true, upsert: true }
  ).populate(populateFields);

  return res.status(200).json({ updatedPost });
}
```

Comment: @DhananjaiPai See, the copied code works fine. I tried it too before posting this question. For whatever reason, the corresponding controller doesn't work in my express app. I've edited the question to include the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
comment => comment['id'] === commentId
```

Your `comment` subdocument comes from MongoDB/Mongoose, so `comment['id']` will likely be of type `ObjectID`, which is never equal a `string`. Explicitly call the `toString()` function (or use some other approach for transforming to a `string`) before comparing:

```
comment => comment['id'].toString() === commentId
```

Comment: Yup! I'm an idiot. How did I forget this? Oh well. Thanks!

Comment: Happened to me today as well. Twice ;-)

Comment: This is a mongo find and not a javascript find then!? because there is no ObjectId type in javascript!

Comment: It's `Array.prototype.find()`, but the `id` is an `ObjectId` type.

Answer (score 0):

works fine in the below snippet, copied from your post!
I am assuming it is `posts.comments` in your case and not `comments.find`? Check for typos

```js
const comments = [
  { "id": "5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556", "addedBy": "5b8528131719dc141cf95c99" },
  { "id": "5d9b0ba2f28afc5c3013d4df", "addedBy": "5b8528131719dc141cf95c99" },
  { "id": "5d9b0c26f28afc5c3013d4e0", "addedBy": "5b8528131719dc141cf95c99" }
];

// For instance if commentId is '5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556' 
// the resulting comment object should be {"id":"5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556","addedBy":"5b8528131719dc141cf95c99"}
const commentId = "5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556";

// However, commentToDelete is undefined
const commentToDelete = comments.find(comment => comment["id"] === commentId);

console.log(commentToDelete);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
const result = comments.find(
  ({ id }) => id === commentId,
);
console.log(result)
// should return { id: '5d9b137ff542a30f2c135556', addedBy: '5b8528131719dc141cf95c99' }
```